# Where's the code-behind for sharepoint aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

No doubt I'm missing something very obvious here - but I'm new to sharepoint so please bear with me.

I've successfully added a master page, created a content type and have created an aspx page for my custom content type - but I can't find its cs file!?

Is there another way in which code-behind is implemented in sharepoint solutions? It seems to be similar when creating controls. I'm used to standard asp .net c# web application development were all of the aspx pages come with the code-behind files 'as standard.'

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SharePoint, you can have a code-behind class, but it needs to be in an assembly, not in an aspx.cs code-behind file.

Using Visual Studio 2010, the Page directive for your aspx page would look something like this:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
    Inherits="MyNamspace.MyPage, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    %>
```

You can then create a `MyNamspace.MyPage` class and do everything you would do in a regular code-behind file.

If you take a look at the out of the box aspx pages in the 14 hive\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS directory, you will see, while some pages have inline code (which is allowed in layouts), almost every page inherits from a class in one of the SharePoint assemblies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Rich - appreciate it. So why is this different to standard asp .net projects? Why is there all this messing around as opposed to the code-behind classes coming 'as standard'?

Comment: Because SharePoint pages can be added/modified in SharePoint Designer and even through the browser, inline code and code-behind pages are not allowed for safety, performance, and even functional reasons. For more information on the differences, see [ASP.NET vs. SharePoint: Page Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512772.aspx)

Comment: Getting error `Could not load the assembly '$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.` I have added .cs file in the folder where my aspx file reside. I am also new to SP.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question with additional, specific details, rather than trying to resolve this in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Code-Behind is hidden by design from both 2007 and 2010 versions. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862025%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to enable it on a per location basis (PageParserPath).

You'll be better off in the long run in terms of supportability, maintenance and management to stick to convention in SharePoint and use controls rather than code-behind if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul! Yes by all means - I'll do what is best practice with regards to sharepoint development - I'm just wondering why it's the case. I've obviously used C# a lot to add server-side functionality to my pages so now shifting all the responsibility to web controls seems alien to me - and I can't really see why it's the case. I'll keep reading anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

you should open your `sharepoint .aspx` page in sharepoint designer and add [`inherit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yk8s7sk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statements with your .cs class.

something like :

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Namespace.ClassName,Namespace,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=tokenid" %>
```

one thing is remain as earlier @Paul's Answer you should enable it on a per location basis [(PageParserPath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862025%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: But I'm assuming that the use of code-behind is 'discouraged' (or at least not as encouraged as if working in a standard asp .net solution) as we have to go to these extra measures to enable it, is this right? Thanks a lot for your response @Jigs.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to ask this in the SharePoint dedicated site. You can find it [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

But answering you question, there is no code behind available for you in SharePoint pages, at least in MOSS 2007. Not sure about SharePoint 2010 exactly, but must be the same.

Comment: Thanks Dante, appreciate the response.